# How to center placeholder and text in React Material UI TextField

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

Current Design:

[image: Current design]

Expected design:

[image]

The TextField tag looks like this:

```
<TextField
        multiline={false}
        autoFocus
        placeholder={props.defaultAmt}
        helperText="Enter amount to pay"
        margin="normal"
        InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">₹</InputAdornment>
        }}
        />
```

I want to center everything in the TextField. I have tried using `textAlign: 'center'` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override the `positionStart` rule in the `InputAdornment` component, by a margin percentage depending on your size and other parameters that affect your Textfield style. I would suggest something like this (I am supposing you are generating your styles with `makeStyles`, but adapt by your own means).

To center the helperText, just add a Typography component into the prop, since it is of a node type. Add a style to the Typography component to center the text and it should work:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  centerAdornment: {
    marginLeft: "50%" // or your relevant measure
  },
  centerText: {
    textAlign: "center"            
  }
}));
```

And the overriding:

```
<TextField
    multiline={false}
    autoFocus
    placeholder={props.defaultAmt}
    helperText={
                  <Typography 
                    variant="caption" 
                    className={classes.centerText}
                    display="block"
                  >
                      Enter amount to pay
                  </Typography>
               }
    margin="normal"
    InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment 
                 position="start"
                 classes={{ positionStart: classes.centerAdornment}}
            >
                ₹
            </InputAdornment>
    }}
/>
```

Comment: This works perfectly for the text and placeholder. Any solution for centering the bottom text?

Comment: @user3787635 I updated my answer for the bottom text as well.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. As far as I know, this is not in docs. How did you know about all these? Sorry, I am new to react and material UI.

Comment: @user3787635 Welcome. Overriding rules and classes is in the docs for each component in the API section [here for the textfield](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api) and [here for the InputAdornment](https://material-ui.com/api/input-adornment/#css). Hope that helps in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Child div alignment and reducing TextBox width to achieve this. Create style like this,

```
const styles = {
   textBox: {
   "& $div": {
        justifyContent: "center",
       "& $input": {
          width: "30%"
        }
     },
   "& $p": {
      alignSelf: "center"
   }
}
};
```

And then set the style to the TextField

```
<TextField
   className={props.classes.textBox}
   multiline={false}
   autoFocus
   placeholder={"5000"}
   helperText="Enter amount to pay"
   margin="normal"
   InputProps={{
       startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">₹</InputAdornment>
      }}
  />
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-57852393-py2jj) is the working CodeSandbox example.

Answer (score 1):

for helper, simple do:

```
<TextField
...
error={isError}
helperText={errorMessage}
FormHelperTextProps={{
  style: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hintStyle={{ width: '600px', textAlign: 'center' }}
```

Add this prop and try

Comment: Doesn't work. It just increases the width of the TextField to 600px.

Answer (score 0):

Add `inputProps` to `Textfield` asking for centering text. Works for input and  placeholder.

```js
<Textfield
  ...
  inputProps={{ style: { textAlign: 'center' } }}
  ...
/>
```